# JS: Why doesn't the image brightness change when the image onclick event fires?

Tags: javascript

I have an image on a page with its brightness set to `0%`. When the user clicks it, the brightness should become `100%`

```html
  <img src="http://placekitten.com/200/300"
       style="filter: brightness(0%);"
       onclick="this.style.filter = 'brightness(100%);'; console.log('clicked!')">
```

(JSFiddle [here](https://jsfiddle.net/cvrxq6z3/1/))

I can see from the log messages that the `onclick` event fires, but the image remains unchanged. How do I change the image brightness when the image is clicked?

Comment: Drop the semicolon from the value you set to filter, i.e. you should assign `'brightness(100%)'` to `.filter`.

Comment: This is the right answer. If you have a moment, post it as an answer and I'll green tick it.

Answer (score 0):

Try doing it like this.
I updated your fiddle.

https://jsfiddle.net/ea1n043c/2/

```js
let img = document.getElementsByTagName("img")[0];

img.addEventListener("click", function() {
  console.log(this);
  this.style.filter = "brightness(100%)";
});
```

```html
<img src="http://placekitten.com/200/300"
       style="filter: brightness(0%);">
```

For me it has worked directly. Cheers